# Cron job that outputs "hello world" every minute to the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

This is my first time playing with cron jobs and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've read the three most upvoted questions on this but it still won't work.

`sayhello.sh`, which has been made executable with `chmod -x` and is located at `/home/user`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=0.0 /home/user/sayhello.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

A shell on its own has no way to interact with the user's desktop  - it needs to be attached to a terminal device of some kind. For example:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -- /home/user/sayhello.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 xterm -e /home/user/sayhello.sh
```

You may need to arrange for the terminal to stay open after the command exits - either through its preferences, or by adding a command such as `read a` to the bottom of your script (so that the shell blocks waiting for user input).

Comment: You could redirect the output of `echo` to a terminal process, like e.g.: `home/user/sayhello.sh > /dev/pts/1`  if there is a terminal process using that device.

Comment: BTW I don't think `0.0` is a valid DISPLAY indicator. I would try something like `:0`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try sudo chmod +x sayhello.sh?

I noticed you said -x, perhaps that is the issue. -x removes permissions to execute whilst +x adds it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting all asterisks `* * * * *` tells crontab to run the command every minute of every day of every week of every month. You have to specify the times when you want to run the script:

```
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```